# Does anyone know this Resistor Code?

Tags: resistors

Hey everyone I am recently trying to map out a faulty circuit board on LTSpice and have come to a grinding stop. there is a resistor that I honestly cannot decifer the code for and sadly my multimeter is on the fritz..... I am attaching a picture of the resistor for reference, any help would be greatly appreciated![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P4wJ.jpg)

Comment: For future reference: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/res_2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

brown-black-green: I’d say 1MΩ.

Comment: somewhat misleading Mfg paint if yellow is for 5% instead of gold and starting from middle instead of end

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 have you seen the price of gold lately? :-)

Comment: $3/oz?  https://goo.gl/J9Ho2A

Comment: Yeah, "gold" paint is some base metal, or mica, flakes and yellow dye

Comment: Color compound is poor quality. Tolerance band seems to be painted over another color. No ethics at all anymore. Best quality is done with epoxy paints.